# access a folder in 'public' directory of laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, laravel

How can I access a folder placed in the `public` directory of my default laravel installation. This question is for both - `testing` as well as `live` purpose.

**While Testing-**

I am testing on windows using XAMPP's apache http server. I have placed my app's root folder in the `htdocs` folder of XAMPP. Thus, when I try to access a folder in public directory, `'localhost/myappname/public/blog'` it redirects me to `'localhost/blog'`.

I don't want this behavior. *I want it to pick up the `'index.php'` file present at `'localhost/myappname/public/blog/'` location*. But it doesn't do so.

**While Live-**

I have my site live on ubuntu with apache http server. When I try to access `'mysitename.com/blog'` in the *firefox*, it *gives me this error* -

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this 
address in a way that will never complete.
```

I have no hint about what's wrong. I have tried spending two days working with laravel's default `.htaccess` file(in `public` folder) and apache `httpd.conf` but still not able to resolve it. Have searched a lot over stackoverflow and google but still no clue about where I am wrong. Please guide me.

**Added:**

The content of `.htaccess` file is -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve other url/actions?

Comment: Show your Laravel `.htaccess` contents

Comment: @Creator Yes I am able to resolve other ones.

Comment: @RahilWazir Kindly elaborate and help me solve it. I am not able to find a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `Alias` feature of apache to overcome this problem. I added an alias for `'/blog'` in my virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment this line in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment it or strip out from the file. This will solve both your directory `/blog` issue as well as redirect loop issue.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't solve the problem. It still loops if I call '/blog/'.

Comment: @halkujabra It won't loop. There is no other rules for redirection how does it redirect for you? Make sure you have removed the cache of your browser.